# pom.xml file is missing when import maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

pom.xml file is not shown when import maven project

process is like

1.Open Eclipse

2.Click **File > Import**

3.Type **Maven**

4.**Select Existing Maven Projects**

5.Click **Next**

6.Click **Browse** and select the folder that is the root of the Maven project (probably contains the **pom.xml** file)

**but pom.xml is not shown is not shown**

the screenshots are below

**pom.xml is not shown**
[image]

but actually the file exist the same path
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Your're selecting a folder so individual files will not be shown

Comment: actually i want to select the pom.xml file, so i choose the file path not selecting the folder..

Comment: You need to select the folder, not the `pom.xml`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it.
the solution :

You have to change the build system the default is Gradle when you create project change and select Maven build system.

Comment: I don't _think_ this is relevant to the issue the OP is describing. They simply haven't realised that they can't select an individual file from a "Select Folder" window.